# Java: Reading csv file into array error

Tags: java, csv

So i have a project that takes data from a csv file.I already passed each column into a string array. when i try to take the contents of that array and put the data into arrays of their own it passes an error because the column title is being read and i cant edit the file (req for the project).

Crime.java

```
package crimestat;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Crime {

    private String Label[];
    private int Year[];
    private int Population[];
    private int Violent[];
    private double Violent_Rate[];
    private int Murder[];
    private double Murder_Rate[];
    private int Rape[];
    private double Rape_Rate[];
    private int Robery[];
    private double Robery_Rate[];
    private int Assault[];
    private double Assault_Rate[];
    private int Property[];
    private double Property_Rate[];
    private int Burglary[];
    private double Burglary_Rate[];
    private int Larceny[];
    private double Larceny_Rate[];
    private int Vehicle[];
    private double Vehicle_Rate[];

    public Crime() {
        Label = null;
        Year = null;
        Population = null;
        Violent = null;
        Violent_Rate = null;
        Murder = null;
        Murder_Rate = null;
        Rape = null;
        Rape_Rate = null;
        Robery = null;
        Robery_Rate = null;
        Assault = null;
        Assault_Rate = null;
        Property = null;
        Property_Rate = null;
        Burglary = null;
        Burglary_Rate = null;
        Larceny = null;
        Larceny_Rate = null;
        Vehicle = null;
        Vehicle_Rate = null;
    }

    public String get_Label(int i){
        return Label[i];
    }

    public int get_Year(int i){
        return Year[i];
    }

    public void set_Label(String[] Label){
        this.Label = Label;
    }

    public void set_Year(int i, Crime crime){
        this.Year[i] = Integer.parseInt(crime.get_Label(0));
    }

}
```

testCrime.java

```
package crimestat;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class testCrime {

    static Crime obj = new Crime();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner file = null;
        int n=0;
        try {
            file = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Crime.csv")));
            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                obj.set_Label(file.nextLine().split(","));
                obj.set_Year(n,obj); 
                System.out.println(obj.get_Year(n));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Year"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at crimestat.Crime.set_Year(Crime.java:69)
at crimestat.testCrime.main(testCrime.java:20)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQt8n.png)

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary to edit *file*.
Since the *first column* is *title*. you can store data from second column on.

the code as below:

```
    file = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Crime.csv"))); 

    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        String curLine = file.nextLine();
        obj.set_Label(curLine.substring(curLine.indexOf(",")+1).split(","));//filter the first column
        obj.set_Year(n,obj); 

        System.out.println(obj.get_Year(n));

    }
}
catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

 //update set_Label method
 public void set_Label(String[] Label){
     this.Label = new int[Label.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < Label.length;i++){
         this.Label[i] = Integer.valueOf(Label[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Im sorry you must have misunderstood,

Comment: Im sorry you must have misunderstood, if i do  'obj.set_Label(file.nextLine().split(","));
System.out.println(obj.get_Label(0));' I get the output of Year, 1994, 1995 ... ect

Comment: but the error happens when trying to put String Label[0] into int Year[n] because year is a string the error is thrown.

Comment: @paul minniti oh yes, but it's similar for you to convert every String like "1997" into Integer like 1997, just use Integer.valueOf(String value) API

Comment: @paul minniti I have add `set_Label method`